# github pull request branch rebase detection

Tags: git, github

I am looking for simple way to find out if pull request branch is already rebased on top of current master before merging it via github web interface. So far I have to check the parent commit hash and compare it with latest master commit hash. I would like to see some true/false icon next to merge button or something to avoid merging non-rebased braches. Any suggestions or possible plugins / browser extensions etc. ?

Comment: Please review my answer and let me know if you left out any information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such plugin which can detect whether a pull request branch has been rebased on top of the master branch.  In any case, you should probably make a habit of always reviewing both the local and master branches before merging the pull request on GitHub.  But I see a bigger fundamental problem with your workflow.  It seems that you are attempting to merge rebased feature branches into master via GitHub.  This defeats the main purpose of rebasing.

The whole point of rebasing a local feature branch on master is to "get ahead" of master so that you can fast-forward the master branch with all of the commits from your feature.  A diagram would help to explain this better:

```
master: A <- B
feature*: A <- B <- C <- D
(* after rebasing feature branch on master)
```

Now if you were to issue a `git push origin feature:master` you will **fast-forward** the master branch with the entire set of commits making up your feature.  Now master would look like the feature branch:

```
master: A <- B <- C <- D
```

Note that there is no merging involved here.  You literally push each commit from your feature directly onto the master branch.  On the other hand, here is what master would look like if you merged the feature branch via a GitHub pull request:

```
master: A <- C <- M
```

Here, M is the merge commit containing your entire feature branch which has now been squashed.  Clearly, these are two very different results, and you should think carefully about what your organization actually wants in their Git workflow.

Finally, take note that GitHub likes to enforce a merge-based workflow.  If you find yourself reviewing a pull request, you should realize that it is very likely you will be undoing the careful work someone did to rebase his feature on master.  It is possible to use rebase with GitHub, but you have to work around the pull requests.